# How to round off floating values in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I'm carrying some mathematical operations on **datatable** fields as follows

**Sample DT:**

```
py_DT = dt.Frame({'junction' : ['BroadwayCycleTrack-N','BroadwayCycleTrack-N',
                 'Burke Gilman Trail','Burke Gilman Trail','Elliot Bay','Elliot Bay'],
                 'time_window' : ['N','MD','M','M','N','MD'],
                 'total_bus' :[3526,8732,6732,9821,6473,9273] 
                 })
```

I would like to calculate a percentage of busses  passed thorough by each junction as

**Code chunk**

```
py_DT[:,{'perc_of': f.total_bus/dt.sum(f.total_bus)},by(f.junction)]
```

Here a new field with a name perc_of holds the calculated value in floating numbers such as

0.287649 and 0.712351 for crossing **BroadwayCycleTrack-N**

Here i was trying to make use of dt.math module to get the floating numbers rounded since the F expression in DT is not allowing python's **round** method.

**Code chunks:**

```
py_DT[:,{'perc_of': dt.math.trunc(f.total_bus/dt.sum(f.total_bus))},by(f.junction)]

py_DT[:,{'perc_of': dt.math.floor(f.total_bus/dt.sum(f.total_bus))},by(f.junction)]

py_DT[:,{'perc_of': dt.math.ceil(f.total_bus/dt.sum(f.total_bus))},by(f.junction)]

py_DT[:,{'perc_of': dt.math.trunc(f.total_bus/dt.sum(f.total_bus))},by(f.junction)]
```

They are not getting worked out to round off 0.287649 to 0.28 or 0.287, is there any other function i should try for it?. i was searching for it documentation but i couldn't find an appropriate one for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dt.math.rint()` function (https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/math.html#rint) rounds to the nearest integer.

There is no direct equivalent of python's `round()` function, but you are welcome to make a Feature Request at https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues to get it implemented.

For now, rounding to a specific number of digits can be achieved by multiplying a column by a power of 10, then rounding, then dividing again:

```
dt.math.rint(f[0] * 1000) / 1000
```

Comment: Ok, I will make a request for it meanwhile I will go with work around